# Equivalent to target="_self" programmatically in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to do a full reload of the app using

```
$state.go('/', {}, {reload: true});
```

which would have the same effect as if the user clicked a link with `target="_self"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found this solution from the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

```
$window.location.href = '/';
```